# How can I check which shell I am currently using?

Tags: shell, bash, terminal, tcsh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test what shell I am using in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)

An echo $SHELL will only display the value of the SHELL variable which would indicate the default shell on the system.

But I might not be always using the default shell on my system:

```
$ bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ csh
% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
%
```

How can I easily figure out what shell I am using?