# How to test what shell I am using in a terminal?

Tags: shell

How to check what shell I am using in a terminal? What is the shell I am using in MacOS?

Comment: echo $SHELL, no?

Comment: @innocent-world No, `echo #SHELL` is not quite it. See # 3 in the [Answer by geekosaur](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9504/56752).

Comment: I am not so sure that "shell" has a well defined meaning. For example, you might run `xterm -e /bin/cat`  but I am not happy calling `/bin/cat` a shell.

Comment: Also some shells (like [scsh](https://scsh.net)) dont use POSIX shell like syntax.

Answer (score 114):

Several ways, from most to least reliable (and most-to-least "heavy"):

1. `ps -p$$ -ocmd=`.  (On Solaris, this may need to be `ps -p$$ -ofname=` and on macOS and on BSD should be `ps -p$$ -ocommand=`.)
2. Check for `$BASH_VERSION`, `$ZSH_VERSION`, and other shell-specific variables.
3. Check `$SHELL`; this is a last resort, as it specifies your *default* shell and not necessarily the *current* shell.

Comment: Should you mention `$0` too?

Comment: I don't like `$0` because it's more complicated: (1) it may be just the basename, (2) it may have '-' on the front to designate it as a login shell.

Comment: `ps -p$$ -ocmd=""` is prettier :-)

Comment: @geekosaur: maybe so, but `$0` still seems more useful than `$SHELL`: wouldn't you agree?  You could always pipe it through `sed` to remove the '-'.

Comment: On Mac, #1 is `ps -p $$ -o comm=""`. Also, for those wondering, $$ is the [shell process ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell).

Comment: If you're running `tcsh`, `$tcsh` and `$version` will be set. These are shell variables, not environment variables. If you're running a non-tcsh version of `csh`, I don't think there are any distinctive variables. And of course the syntax used to check variables differs between csh/tcsh on the one hand, and sh/ksh/bash/zsh on the other.

Comment: On HP-UX, `ps -p$$ -ocommand=` doesn't work either ("`illegal option`" for each of the letters after `-o`). The same with `ps -p$$ -ofname`.

Comment: `$BASH_VERSION` is enough to check whether the currently running is bash. I'd use this to detect whether any shell other than bash is being used.

Comment: #1 is definitely heavier - running a command - but how is it more reliable that variables like `$ZSH_VERSION`?

Comment: I wouldn't put `ps -p$$ -ocmd=` to the top of "reliable" list. I just was getting errors in my script, and then turned out the command returned not bash, not zsh, but "bash test.sh". So no, you can't rely on this.

Comment: Yes, 3 not works well. I have set up a terminal profile to run bash on startup. In this case I use bash but $SHELL returns zsh.

Answer (score 64):

I've found that the following works in the four shells I have installed on my system (bash, dash, zsh, csh):

```
$ ps -p $$
```

The following works on zsh, bash, and dash, but not on csh:

```
$ echo $0
```

Comment: Also does not work on fish.

Comment: I think that @jiliagre's answer is probably would I would use today.  On fish `%self` can be used in place of `$$`

Comment: It would be great if you explained what you are doing, why this works, what the `$$` is etc

Answer (score 10):

As the question asks for the shell used and does not talk about the potential arguments passed to it, here is a way that avoid showing them:

```
$ ps -o comm= -p $$
ksh93
```

Answer (score 8):

A note about some lighter implementations (Android phones, busybox, etc.): `ps` doesn't always have support for the `-p` switch, but you can accomplish the search with a command like `ps | grep "^$$ "`.  (This `grep` regex will uniquely identify the PID, so there will not be any false positives.)

Answer (score 7):

There are two really simple ways:

- Using [**ps**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#EXAMPLES) command:

  ```
  ps -o comm= $$
  ```

  or

  ```
  ps -h -o comm -p $$
  ```

  where:

  - `-h` or finishing all options with `=` for not showing any header.
  - `-o comm` for showing only the process basename (`bash` instead of `/bin/bash`).
  - `-p <PID>` list only process whith PID form list suplied.
- Using the [**/proc**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) process information pseudo-file system:

  ```
  cat /proc/$$/comm
  ```

  This option behaves exactly as the `ps` command above.

  or

  ```
  readlink /proc/$$/exe
  ```

  This `/proc/PID/exe` links to the file being executed, which in this case would point to /bin/bash, /bin/ksh, etc.

  For getting only the name of the shell you can just use

  ```
  basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe)
  ```

  **This is the only option that will always give the same result even if you are in an script, sourced code, or terminal, as links to the binary of the shell interpreter in use.**

  **Warning** You must be aware that this will show the ultimate binary, so ksh may be linked to ksh93 or sh to bash.

The usage of `/proc` is really useful via the `/proc/self`, which links to the PID of the current command.

Comment: `basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe)` is Korn/POSIX shell syntax. Won't work in csh/tcsh/rc/es/akanga/fish. `$$` won't work in `rc`/`es`/`akanga`/`fish`.

Comment: `basename $(readlink /proc/$$/exe)` is the only command here that could work for me in a docker image with no `ps` installed.

Comment: macOS (which the user in the question is using) does not have a `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

A mix of all the other answers, compatible with Mac (comm), Solaris (fname) and Linux (cmd):

```
ps -p$$ -o cmd="",comm="",fname="" 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^-//' | grep -oE '\w+' | head -n1
```

Comment: this gives me my current directory name;  also, under `csh` and `tcsh` it gives me `Ambiguous output redirect.`

Comment: This is also what Anaconda uses (version 2022.05) in it's `[env]/bin/activate` script to detect shell type. A comment in that file explicitly links to this answer.

Comment: `head` takes the first match which is bin from /bin/foosh in most cases. `tail -n1` would take the last, which is probably the desired shell

Answer (score 3):

If you have it saved in your environment variables you can use the following:

```
echo $SHELL
```

#### For accuracy in many different shells you should use

```
ps -p $$
```

Why does this work?

```
echo $$ # 998
```

#### What is that number?

It's the `process id` of the current shell.

`$` expands to the same value as the current shell.

`$$` process ID of the parent in a sub shell

If you only want then name of the shell you could use

```
ps -p $$ | awk '{if(NR>1)print}' | awk '$0=$NF' | tr -d -
```

In a nutshell we are taking the output of the process sub shell and piping it to some formatting tools awk, sed and tr all work for this, removing the first 3 columns, the first line of output, and then the - gives just the name of the shell. Consider putting that into a function for ease later.

Comment: That will most likely return the pathname of the shell executable of your login shell.  It is not certain that the login shell is what you are currently running though.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more value and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I set `$MYSHELL` for future tests in my shell-agnostic `~/.aliases`:

```
unset MYSHELL
if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && type zstyle >/dev/null 2>&1; then           # zsh
  MYSHELL=`command -v zsh`
elif [ -x "$BASH_VERSION" ] && type caller >/dev/null 2>&1; then        # bash
  MYSHELL=`command -v bash`
elif [ -x "$shell" ] && which setenv |grep -l builtin >/dev/null; then  # tcsh
  echo "DANGER: this script is likely not compatible with C shells!"
  sleep 5
  setenv MYSHELL "$shell"
fi

# verify
if [ ! -x "$MYSHELL" ]; then
  MYSHELL=`command -v "$(ps $$ |awk 'NR == 2 { print $NF }')"`
  [ -x "$MYSHELL" ] || MYSHELL="${SHELL:-/bin/sh}"  # default if verify fails
fi
```

The `tcsh` section is likely unwise to roll into a POSIX-style script since it's so radically different (thus the warning and five second pause).  (For one, `csh`-style shells can't do `2>/dev/null` or `>&2`, as noted in the famous [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) rant.)

Answer (score 1):

The pid of the running shell is given by the var $$ (in most shells).

```
whichsh="`ps -o pid,args| awk '$1=='"$$"'{print $2}'`"
echo "$whichsh"
```

Using backticks to make jsh (Heirlomm shell) work.

In many shells the direct test of `ps -o args= -p $$` works, but `busybox ash` fails on that (solved).

The check that `$1` must be equal to `$$` removes most false positives.

The last `;:` are used to keep the shell running for ksh and zsh.

Tests on more systems will help, please make a comment if it doesn't work for you.

Does not work in `csh` type of shells.

Comment: On OS/X, in my tests, I get at least 3 lines, one for the shell, one for `/usr/lib/dyld`, one for `/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64`.

Comment: Yes, it now only selects the entries in /bin and /usr/bin

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Maybe it is better now?

Answer (score 0):

Good question me too on my Mac had the same doubt.

Another method, dirty but "it works", it really simple; you should launch a command that does not exist. The the shell reply the classical "command not found", but first shows its name. :-)

```
~$ piripicchio
-bash: piripicchio: command not found
```

and

```
~ % piripicchio
zsh: command not found: piripicchio`
```

---

Also, you could note that zsh prompt is "%" and bash is "$" but my root on bash has "%" too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to check the current shell in a *shell script using a shebang* (because the other answers will give the script name in this case):

```
ps -p$PPID
```

or to get only the name:

```
ps -p$PPID | grep -v "PID" | awk '{print $4}'
```

Explanation:

- `$PPID` is the process id of the parent to the current process (the shell executing the current script)
- `ps -p` gets information on the given process
- `grep -v "PID"` removes the header line
- `awk '{print $4}'` gets the fourth column (which is the command name)

Answer (score -1):

`echo ${0//-/}`

This one returns `bash` or `zsh` even if it's a login shell (ie. starting with `-`).

Comment: This would only work in shells that support the non-standard expansion `${variable//pattern/replacement}`.