# 'switch' based on shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tcsh, csh

I would like to *source* (i.e. not *call*) a script from any shell (bash/csh are the primary targets, but fish, zsh, ksh, and rc would also be interesting).

I would like if the script can be a single file - i.e. not a file for each shell dialect.

Can I do that?

I am thinking of something similar to:

```
  if shell is bash then
    # bash code here
  else
    if shell is csh then
      # csh code here
    else
      if shell is xxxsh then
        # xxxsh code here
      fi
    endif
  fi
```

So I can do:

```
csh% source my_script
bash$ . my_script
```

The trouble is - of course that `if` is not the same in each dialect, so I somehow need to use syntax that is valid for every shell.

*Edit*

Detecting the shell is the first step of which [determine shell in script during runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/determine-shell-in-script-during-runtime/71137#71137) is doing a great job of.

An equally important step is how the code for the different sections for  shells should be quoted to not confuse other shells. Think: How can you in the section for bash have a `<<here_document` containing all characters in all combinations legal in bash but illegal in any other shell without this confusing the other shells. This is not covered by any of the answers/linked answers.

Comment: This sort of thing is possible, but it usually requires very specific workarounds and extreme cleverness. I don't think there's really a generic and extensible way to do it.

Comment: Here's an example of some extreme cleverness from one of our own: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/117549

Comment: Related: [How do I *reliably* and *simply* get the current shell interpreter name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220663/23408) and [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567/23408) and other questions answered by [Stéphane Chazelas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565).

Comment: @Scott I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP here wants to be able to execute a different set of instructions based on the shell being used. While detecting the shell is indeed part of the solution, it is not enough. Once you've detected it, how can you do one thing for one shell and another for a different shell without separating things into different files?

Comment: @terdon: I believe that we're interpreting the question differently.  You seem to believe that the OP wants different functionality in the different cases.  I believe that the idea is "if shell is bash, then execute the bash *version* of the code; else if shell is csh, then execute the csh *version* of the code"; etc.

Comment: @Scott yes, exactly, but without resorting to separate files. They seem to want a script that can be sourced and, depending on who's sourcing, run one code or another. That's why I don't think it's a dupe. The question you linked to is only about detecting the shell, it doesn't deal with rest of the issue and that's the hard bit.

Comment: @terdon: So you think [How do I *reliably* and *simply* get the current shell interpreter name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/220663/23408) is a better dupe?  That's talking about a script that gets sourced into `.zshrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile` and has to know which shell it's in to know how to behave.

Comment: even if this is possible, you really don't want to do this.  instead of suffering the oddities of just one shell, you are inflicting the horrible quirks of lots of shells on yourself.

Comment: @Scott yes that is indeed a better dupe target. Thanks.

Comment: It's crazy to consider csh today. POSIX is my maximum tolerance actually.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing fragments of code for every shell, you should just write portable code, which can be interpreted by most shells. You should look at the [POSIX Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). This is a standard how a shell (which honors POSIX) should interpret code.

Many shells, like `bash`, can be configured to behave like a POSIX shell. Every shell has his won features and specific notations. Aviod them completely in portable scripts.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned `csh` which, among its many other failings, is most certainly not POSIX-compliant so this isn't likely to help them much.

Comment: anyone writing csh scripts should be advised not to and referred to http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot and http://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/  Way back in the dark ages of the 1980s, csh made a pretty decent interactive shell because it had neat features like history recall and editing.  Other, better, shells have long since gained and surpassed those features without the drawbacks of csh.

Answer (score 2):

For csh-like versus Bourne-like, you could do:

```
start=:#||:<<"goto end="

echo "(t)csh code here"
if { bindkey >& /dev/null } then
  echo tcsh
endif

goto end=

echo Bourne-like code here
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  echo bash
fi

end=:
```

Explained:

- `start=:` would be treated as a label declaration in `csh`, and variable assignment in `sh`, so two harmless operations.
- In `start=:#`, that `#` is treated as a comment leader `csh`, but not in `sh` as it's not a separate token. So what's after that is commented out for `csh` but not for `sh`.
- a variable assignment is `sh` has a success exit status (as long as the assignments doesn't involve command substitutions), so the command right of the `||` operator won't be run.
- That `:<<"goto end="...goto end` command is not run but is parsed, and ignored (the fact that `"goto end"` is quoted prevents various expansions inside the here document). A note however: in the Bourne shell (and only in the Bourne shell), a temporary file is still created.
- So the whole section until `goto end=` is ignored by Bourne-like shell and run by `csh`. `goto end=` causes `csh` to ignore the part between that and `end=:` (a harmless variable assignment in Bourne-like shells).

The more shell support you add, the trickier it gets. For `fish` especially, it's quite tricky as it checks the syntax of the whole script event the parts it doesn't run.

See also:

- [determine shell in script during runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137) for an example of polyglot code.
- [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205569) for code working on sh/csh/rc/fish families (I wrote that one when we had that discussion about `parallel` invoking a shell)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the reason you want to do that is for portability. The above answers give you a clue. If you assume that say, the Bourne shell (sh) is the least common denominator, and available 'everywhere' (Linux, Solaris, Unix, AIX etc) then you can put a `#!/bin/sh` at the start of your script, and write all your script using only the features of sh.
(I think that in Linux, sh is just an alias for bash, because bash is a superset of the Bourne shell, but no matter, it should still work.)

A slight refinement is to assume that `sh` is always there, but you might need the extra power and convenience of some of the more advanced shells. 
so you could write a version of the script for each of the shells you support, e.g. script.bash, script.zsh, script.ksh, script.csh etc. each one beginning with its own shebang line, and then in the script.sh file you would say something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ -e /bin/ksh ]] ; then 
 ./script.ksh
 exit
elif [[ -e /bin/csh ]] ; then
 ./script.csh
 exit
fi
```

etc.

A further suggestion is to study the source code of the auto-tools tool chain.  Those things that run when you  do  a ./configure ; make  ; make install.
The GNU folks have done a lot of clever things to ensure that their scripts run in all environments.

Comment: The OP _specifically_ mentioned they want to avoid having a separate script per shell. Also, your solution is checking for the existence of the shells on the system, not for what interpreter is currently reading the script, so that won't help either. Finally, note that, these days, `sh` is often a link to `dash`, but even when it is indeed a link to `bash`, calling `bash` as `sh` causes it to run in POSIX mode and behave more like traditional `sh` than `bash`.