# How to detect the command interpreter from within a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test what shell I am using in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)

I want to detect which interpreter a shell script is using.  For example the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

issue_interpreter_name()
```

Should reveal the interpreter:

```
bash
```

Comment: @jw013 more or less the same question but jippie's answer is better then the ones in the linked question :-)

Answer (score 12):

```
#!/bin/sh  
ps h -p $$ -o args='' | cut -f1 -d' '
```

- `ps` process list
- `h` do not print column headers
- `-p <PID>` list only process id PID
- `$$` replaced by the shell with current PID
- `-o args` print the command line, no other information
- `cut` cut the output into parts
- `-f1` print only the first field
- `-d' '` use a space as a field separator

  `$ ./testje`

  `/bin/sh`

Comment: On Mac OX X I get an additional line with the header `ARGS`. With `-o args=''` you can remove the header

Comment: Verified Matteo's comment on Linux (ubuntu 12.04) and works as designed. Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a local user, the 7th field of /etc/passwd is their shell. Are you looking for the currently preferred shell?

Comment: -1 The default login shell is not necessrily the one currently running.