# Difference between "echo $SHELL" and "which bash"

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I am trying to determine the location of bash interpreter on my Solaris system and I am a bit confused. When I type:

```
echo $SHELL
```

The resulting path is:

```
/bin/bash
```

And when I type:

```
which bash
```

I get:

```
/usr/bin/bash
```

Can anyone please explain this discrepancy?

Comment: A good thing to note is that [`which` is not really a useful command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081).

Comment: Also, neither of the two answers are correct about `$SHELL`.  It does not necessarily reflect the currently running shell.  Instead, [`$SHELL` is the user's *preferred shell*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03), which is typically the one set in `/etc/passwd`.  If you start a different shell after logging in, you can not necessarily expect `$SHELL` to match the current shell anymore.

Comment: @jw013 Thank you for your comments and explanation, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: See also [How to test what shell I am using](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)

Comment: Allow me to spamvertise the `wtfis` function from my dotfiles: https://github.com/janmoesen/tilde/blob/01a9f86/.bash/commands#L719 — it combines `type`, `file` and `ls` to show as much information as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your system probably has `bash` installed in multiple locations, whether as different versions of `bash` or just symbolic links.

[`which` is not really a useful command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081) for most purposes - it's not really portable or very usable in scripts.  In general, `type` is better.  The idea behind `which` is to do a `PATH` search for the command you give it as an argument.

`$SHELL` does not necessarily reflect the currently running shell. Instead, [`$SHELL` is the user's preferred shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03), which is typically the one set in `/etc/passwd`. If you start a different shell after logging in, you can not necessarily expect `$SHELL` to match the current shell anymore.

As you can see, `$SHELL` and `which` are completely unrelated.  Neither of these will tell you what shell you are actually running.

A side note: Unfortunately, matching the shell you are currently running to a location in the filesystem is harder than one might think.  This is because binaries are loaded into memory in order to run, and in most systems the copy in memory will continue to run fine even after you delete the original from disk (the kernel may keep the disk copy around in "limbo" until it is really no longer needed).  I don't think there is any portable way to go about this - you'd have to resort to platform specific methods.  For example, on Linux, examining the link `/proc/$$/exe` should give you a decent idea of what *file* is running (where `$$` is the process ID of your running shell).  Unfortunately I am not familiar with Solaris, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are good, but I like to give a demonstration.

```
% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
% which bash
/bin/bash
```

- The first command tells me which shell will be executed by `login` when you log in. In my case, `/bin/zsh`.
- The second command tells me the first occurrence in my `$PATH` the `bash` command can be found.

One does not imply the second, nor vice versa.

I'm not going to restate other people's answers but in addition to that I want to point out some things.

- The default shell on Solaris is `/bin/bash`
- On Solaris `/bin` is a symlink to `./usr/bin`
- The default `$PATH` on Solaris is `/usr/bin:/bin`

That's why you're seeing this behavior.

Comment: The first command shows your default shell, which may be the shell you are currently running, but not always.

Comment: @jordanm: ah, yes you're right. Fixing.

Comment: The default shell is /usr/bin/bash only on Solaris 11. Under Solaris 10 and older it is /bin/sh which is the legacy Bourne shell implementation. Since Solaris 11, /bin/sh is ksh93. Solaris default PATH for non root users is just /usr/bin, having both /usr/bin and /bin would make no sense.

Comment: @jlliagre: You're right regarding S10/S11. About `/bin/` and `/usr/bin` I agree it doesn't make sense, but if you don't have a `PATH` declared that's what the system gives you.

Comment: The PATH is always defined by default on Solaris unless you mess with configuration files. It is set on Solaris 11 to `/usr/bin` for regular users and `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` for root. The default (and redundant) PATH set by bash if unset at launchtime is `/usr/gnu/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:.` This is perhaps where you observe `/bin:/usr/bin`.

Comment: I *just* did it on Solaris 11 and reported exactly what I got.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $SHELL` shows the value of the [`SHELL` environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html#tag_08_03). This is a user configuration, which you can set to the path to your favorite interactive shell. Many programs invoke `$SHELL` when asked to invoke a shell.

<sub>I think all shells leave this variable alone unless it is unset when they start. Bash sets `SHELL` to its own path if the variable is unset when it starts. ATT ksh93 sets `SHELL` to `/bin/sh` if unset (even if `/bin/sh` is some unrelated shell). Ksh (all versions) checks whether `SHELL` is `rsh` when it starts; if it is, it starts as a [restricted shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell).</sub>

`which bash` shows the path to the bash executable (except when it [doesn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command) — you should use `type bash` instead). More precisely, it searches the directories in `$PATH` for an executable called `bash`.

`echo $0`, in an interactive shell, shows the command name that was used to invoke the shell.

`ps $$` (typed from a shell) displays information about the shell process (`$$` is expanded to the process ID of the shell).

`ls -l /proc/$$/exe` shows the full path to the executable for the shell

For example, my favorite shell is zsh, but here I've just started a home-compiled version of bash that isn't in the `$PATH`.

```
% ./bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh4
$ type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash
$ echo $0
./bash
$ readlink /proc/$$/exe
/home/gilles/src/bash-git/bash
$ pwd
/home/gilles/src/bash-git
$ rm bash
$ echo $0
./bash
$ readlink /proc/$$/exe
/home/gilles/src/bash-git/bash (deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$SHELL` is an environment variable set with the path to the current login shell, which in this case is bash. If you were to use the `chsh` command to switch to some other shell (e.g. zsh), then you would see `/bin/zsh` when you ran `echo $SHELL`.

The `which` command actually has nothing to do with a specific shell, other than being responsible for determining which program would be run if you were to call that program directly. You might have several versions of that program in the paths in your $PATH variable that could be run. The reason you see `/bin/bash` when you run `which bash` is because that's where the system first finds the `bash` program in the hierarchy that is `$PATH`.

You can run `which` on *any* command, not just a shell.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "currently active".  It's your login shell, not the shell you're currently typing into.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `which` command searches through directories specified in your `$PATH` variable and returns the first match it finds as this will be the file which will be executed.

`$SHELL` returns the canonical name of the file currently running, e.g., `/bin/bash`. `/usr/bin/bash` is probably a link to `/bin/bash` anyway. Use `$SHELL` to find the name of your current command interpreter.

Comment: It's not the file currently running, it's the default shell.  See other answers.  Also, for what it's worth, I think the symlink is the other way around on Solaris.

Comment: More precisely, /bin/bash and /usr/bin/bash are the very same file, /bin being a symbolic link to /usr/bin.

Comment: I stand corrected. $SHELL is the user's default shell, not the currently running one.

Comment: Regarding other answers about `which` and `type` by @Gilles and @jw013, when using the `tcsh` shell, `which` is a builtin command and `type` is not found. Conclusions: (1) You should know the shell you are running before you enter a command. (2) You should always put `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever is needed) at the top of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Under Solaris, one simple way to know what shell you are running and what launched it is `ptree`, here my shell is ksh:

```
$ ptree $$
408   /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
  1131  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
    1132  /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
      1142  -ksh
        1146  ptree 1142
```

The standard way to get what a command will actually run is to use the [type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html) command.

```
$ type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash
```

Given the fact `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are interchangeable under Solaris (and this is a trend on other Unix like OSes too), whether type bash will return `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` depends only on what first appears on your `PATH` and anyway doesn't matter that much.