# determine shell in script during runtime

Tags: linux, shell-script

As per my knowledge, to determine the current shell we use `echo $0` in the shell. Rather I want my script to check in which shell it is running. So, I tried to print `$0` in the script and it returns the name of the script as it should. So, my question is how can I find which shell is my script running in during runtime?

Comment: what scripting language are you using? Also, worse case, you can always shell out a system command to get the "echo $0" results inside of the script.

Comment: `echo $0` is not an option here ,as the script will run on many different machines where first thing I'll need to check is the shell.

Comment: So what is the scripting language then?

Comment: @BriGuy: It's a unix shell script.

Comment: Well, if you add `#! /bin/sh -` at the top, it will run in `sh`. Do you mean _what variant of `sh` is it?_

Comment: Check the value of `$SHELL`.

Comment: This is similar to: [How to test what shell I am using in a terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)  Perhaps not a dup since this question is specifically about being within a script.  But I think that's the implied context for the other question, because it shouldn't be too hard for a user to know which shell they're running interactively, should it?

Comment: @g4ur4v What do you mean by "using ksh shell script"?  If you know you're using ksh, what are you trying to determine?

Comment: ksh is the shell where I am developing the script...Its not the shell where I might run it.

Comment: Is not this a duplicate of [How to test what shell I am using in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On linux you can use `/proc/PID/exe`.

Example:

```
# readlink /proc/$$/exe
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: That's a bit too specific for me (e.g. on Debian it prints zsh4 or ksh93). `/bin/sed -r -e 's/\x0.*//' /proc/$$/cmdline` gives zsh or ksh instead. (That'd be $0 if shells didn't magically fix this to give the scripts name instead).

Comment: @frostschutz Yours is the best answer, run for the +500!

Comment: Not really. It depends on what the OP really wants. Not reading the link also causes `#!/bin/sh` to return just `sh` even if it's really bash, dash, etc. Can't follow links and not follow links at the same time. Unless you check if it's `sh` and follow then or something, but that solution is plain weird.

Comment: This suffers from the dreaded *All the world's a Linux box* disease. `/proc` is as ugly and unportable as it gets.

Comment: Originally thought of this one as well. See my answer for an OS agnostic solution. :)  Despite the Linux Box Disease, /proc continues to be a great way to access process info.

Comment: @Jens that's why I specified this applies to Linux only. `/proc` is not 'ugly'. `/proc` is often a very elegant solution. Unportable yes, but because something is unportable doesn't make it ugly.

Comment: @Patrick I consider `/proc` ugly because the files in it may come and go at the whim of developers and the contents of files is prone to change without notice, causing endless pain due to bitrot and moving target file formats.

Comment: @frostschutz’s answer doesn’t seem to be portable (doesn’t work with BSD `sed`).

Comment: `/proc` does not change at the whim of developers. `/proc` contents are relied upon by tons of tools, such as `top`, `ps`, `sar`, `ss`, and hundreds/thousands of others. If it changed on a whim, you'd have a few million irritated users & developers.

Comment: Linux only this.

Comment: On illumos `cat /proc/$$/argv | xargs -0` appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 64):

Maybe not what you're asking for, but this should work to some  extent to identify the interpreter currently interpreting it for a few like

1. Thompson shell (`osh`),
2. Bourne shell,
3. Bourne-again shell (`bash`),
4. Korn shell (`ksh88`, `ksh93`, `pdksh`, `mksh`),
5. `zsh`,
6. Policy-compliant Ordinary shell (`posh`),
7. Yet Another shell (`yash`),
8. `rc` shell,
9. `akanga` shell,
10. es shell,
11. `wish` TCL interpreter,
12. `tclsh` TCL interpreter,
13. `expect` TCL interpreter,
14. Perl,
15. Python,
16. Ruby,
17. PHP,
18. JavaScript (nodejs, SpiderMonkey shell and JSPL at least)
19. MS/Wine `cmd.exe`, `command.com` (MSDOS, FreeDOS...).

```
'echo' +"'[{<?php echo chr(13)?>php <?php echo PHP_VERSION.chr(10);exit;?>}\
@GOTO DOS [exit[set 1 [[set 2 package] names];set 3 Tcl\ [info patchlevel];\
if {[lsearch -exact $1 Expect]>=0} {puts expect\ [$2 require Expect]\ ($3)} \
elseif {[lsearch -exact $1 Tk]>=0} {puts wish\ ($3,\ Tk\ [$2 require Tk])} \
else {puts $3}]]]' >/dev/null ' {\">/dev/null \
">"/dev/null" +"\'";q="#{",1//2,"}";a=+1;q='''=.q,';q=%{\"
'echo' /*>/dev/null
echo ">/dev/null;status=0;@ {status=1};*=(" '$' ");~ $status 1&&{e='"\
"';eval catch $2 ^'&version {eval ''echo <='^ $2 ^'&version''}';exit};e='"\
"';if (eval '{let ''a^~a''} >[2] /dev/null'){e='"\
"';exec echo akanga};eval exec echo rc $2 ^ version;\" > /dev/null
: #;echo possibly pre-Bourne UNIX V1-6 shell;exit
if (! $?version) set version=csh;exec echo $version
:DOS
@CLS
@IF NOT "%DOSEMU_VERSION%"=="" ECHO DOSEMU %DOSEMU_VERSION%
@ECHO %OS% %COMSPEC%
@VER
@GOTO FIN
", unless eval 'printf "perl %vd\n",$^V;exit;'> "/dev/null";eval ': "\'';
=S"';f=false e=exec\ echo n=/dev/null v=SH_VERSION;`(eval "f() { echo :
};f")2>$n` $f||$e Bourne-like shell without function
case `(: ${_z_?1}) 2>&1` in 1) $e ash/BSD sh;;esac;t(){
eval "\${$1$v+:} $f &&exec echo ${2}sh \$$1$v";};t BA ba;t Z z;t PO po;t YA ya
case `(typeset -Z2 b=0;$e $b)2>$n` in 00) (eval ':${.}')2>$n&&eval '
$e ksh93 ${.sh.version}';t K pdk;$e ksh88;;esac;case `(eval '$e ${f#*s}$($e 1
)$((1+1))')2>$n` in e12)$e POSIX shell;;esac;$e Bourne-like shell;: }
print "ruby ",RUBY_VERSION,"\n";exit;' ''';import sys
print("python "+sys.version);z='''*/;
s="";j="JavaScript";if(typeof process=="object"){p=console.log;p(process.title
,process.version)}else{p=print;p((f="function")==(t=typeof version)?"string"==
typeof(v=version())?v:(typeof build!=f?"":s= "SpiderMonkey ")+j+" "+v:(t==
"undefined"?j+"?":version)+"\n");if(s)build()}/*
:FIN } *///'''
```

I posted the initial version of that [which_interpreter](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/which_interpreter) *script* circa 2004 on usenet. Sven Mascheck has a (probably more useful to you) script called [whatshell](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/) that focuses on identifying Bourne-like shells. You can also find a merged version of our two scripts [there](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/which_interpreter_ext.html).

Comment: This cannot identify Python 3, only Python 2. To fix that, change `print` to be a function.

Comment: This is the biggest WTF moment of the year so far. +1 for taking portability past sanity.

Comment: It would be nice if it would recognize fish shell.

Comment: @xfix, I remember trying even before adding php and javascript but couldn't find a solution then. The complexity grows exponentially with the number of languages to support (as everything you add must be valid (or at least have unnoticeable side-effects) in all the supported languages) so it would be even more difficult now. I'm not saying it's impossible but that would probably mean dropping support for some other languages.

Comment: This is extremely interesting and impressive, but it identifies `zsh` on my system as `bash 3.2.53(1)-release`.

Comment: @iconoclast, you mean you ran `zsh ./that-script` and it returned `bash 3.2.53(1)-release`? More likely you ran it as `./that-script` from within `zsh` which got it interpreted by your `sh`, and your `sh` happens to be `bash`.

Comment: Yes, the latter:  from an interactive `zsh` session I ran `whatshell.sh`.

Comment: @iconoclast, so it correctly identifies `bash 3.2.53(1)-release` as the interpreter interpreting it.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I use in my .profile to check for various shells on the systems I work on.
It doesn't make fine distinctions between ksh88 and ksh93, but it has never failed me.

Note that it doesn't require a single fork or pipe.

```
# Determine what (Bourne compatible) shell we are running under. Put the result
# in $PROFILE_SHELL (not $SHELL) so further code can depend on the shell type.

if test -n "$ZSH_VERSION"; then
  PROFILE_SHELL=zsh
elif test -n "$BASH_VERSION"; then
  PROFILE_SHELL=bash
elif test -n "$KSH_VERSION"; then
  PROFILE_SHELL=ksh
elif test -n "$FCEDIT"; then
  PROFILE_SHELL=ksh
elif test -n "$PS3"; then
  PROFILE_SHELL=unknown
else
  PROFILE_SHELL=sh
fi
```

Comment: Note that only very recent versions of `ksh93` have `$KSH_VERSION`. That variable comes from `pdksh` and never made it to AT&T ksh88.

Comment: Right, which is why I have the second test for `FCEDIT`.

Comment: Right. Note that `posh` (pdksh with most non-POSIX features removed so you would probably want to call it "sh") has no FCEDIT nor KSH_VERSION but has PS3 (maybe not for long), though it's unlikely for one to have it as a login shell. Also note that the code above wouldn't reflect whether `bash` or `zsh` are in `sh` emulation mode, which may be a problem if you're using `$PROFILE_SHELL` to decide whether or not to enable this or that feature. See also [Sven Mascheck's whatshell](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/) for more you may (or may not) want to check.

Comment: This is the cleanest approach if readability matters.

Answer (score 9):

You could try

```
ps -o args= -p "$$"
```

which will give you the name of the command associated with the script's pid.

Comment: Doesn't work when using a shebang as far as I can tell. http://sprunge.us/QeHD

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisDown, Flup. My bad, I had incorrectly translated `cmd` to `comm` when POSIXifying the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there is the `lsof` command available on your system, you can get the full path of the parent shell executable by getting the parent PID via `ps` and parsing the ouput of `lsof -p $ppid` (see [How to determine the current shell i'm working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530657)).

```
#!/bin/sh
ppid="`ps -p "$$" -o ppid=`"
lsof -nP -p "$ppid" | awk 'NR==3 {print $NF; exit}'
```

Comment: On my system this returns `/`, if I use `NR==4` I get the path to the shells parent.

Comment: Note that POSIX `sh`s have the `$PPID` variable. On `Linux`, you can use `readlink -f "/proc/$PPID/exe"`.

Comment: Please, stop using backticks in shell scripts.  It's rarely the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Portable solution (tested in linux and macOS):

```
ps -o args= -p $$ | egrep -m 1 -o '\w{0,5}sh'
```

where:

```
"ps -o args=" retrieves the command line arguments
"$$" gives you the current PID
"-m 1" to finish searching after the first match
"-o" to only display matching portion
"\w{0,5}sh" regular expression to find things like bash in /bin/bash or ksh in -ksh or sh in sh (Maximum 5 characters+sh)
```

hope it helps

Comment: `egrep` is not universal. `grep -E` would be more "portable", but still non-standard. The `\w` thing is a GNU-ism supported by some `grep` implementation. This returns `sh` when I'm in `zsh` on OpenBSD if I run it as-is (probably because `\w` is only matching a literal `w`).

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Linux land or lacking access to the /proc filesystem or equivelent, you can make use of pstree:

Assuming you have the pid of

On a Mac:

```
./test.sh 
16012
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 00245 wingwong /sbin/launchd
   \-+= 04670 wingwong /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_2052597
     \-+= 11816 root login -pf wingwong
       \-+= 11817 wingwong -bash
         \-+= 16012 wingwong ksh ./test.sh
           \-+- 16013 wingwong pstree -p 16012
```

On a Linux box:

```
./test.sh 
14981
bash(14981)---pstree(14982)
```

The format and style of the output from pstree differs, depending on your environment, but you can enforce ASCII output and then sed/tr/awk/etc. filter the output to get the shell that is running the script.

So a cleaned up output version(works for Mac or Linux OS runs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
pstree  -p $$  | tr ' ()' '\012\012\012' | grep -i "sh$" | grep -v "$0" | tail -1
```

On run yields:

```
./test.sh 
sh
```

And when run with a different shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
pstree  -p $$  | tr ' ()' '\012\012\012' | grep -i "sh$" | grep -v "$0" | tail -1
```

Yields:

```
./test.sh 
ksh
```

No root or special filesystem required. Note, my filtering assumes that the shell binary name ends with sh and that there are no intermediate entries which end with sh. Also assumes that you didn't name your script "sh" or some unfortunate grep pattern that will obliterate information. :) Will require some customization for your own environment to ensure a higher degree of foolproofing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command:

```
$ echo $SHELL
```

to find out the shell from within the script.

Comment: No. `$SHELL` is the shell of choice of the user. Initialised from the login shell of the user. Nothing to do with the currently running shell.