# if/then/else man page

Tags: shell, scripting, man, documentation

I would like to know if there is any man page documenting the construction of the most basic script commands like `if/then/else`, `while`, `for each`, and all the relative switches, like `-eq`, `-e`, `-ge`, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to look at the manual for the specific shell you are using as the exact syntax for using these constructs can vary between shells. Most likely you are using `bash`, so you would do `man bash`. Although there are many cases where you might be using something else. For example many distros use a `POSIX` shell for boot scripts (eg Debian uses `dash`) or a least use `bash` in `POSIX` compliant mode. Usually you can do `man sh` to get the documentation in this case (this will be linked to the man page for the shell used if it is not the original `sh` or Bourne shell).

If you are unsure which shell you are using, see this question - [determine shell in script during runtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/determine-shell-in-script-during-runtime/71137)

Another thing work mentioning is the `help` builtin for bash, it gives an abbreviated version of what is in the manual for the various builtin commands/flow control statements etc. You can use `help` on its own to see a full list of what is available, otherwise you can try things like `help if`, `help for`, `help test` and `help [`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `help`. Note that `[` is simply an alias of `test`, and is **not** part of conditional statement syntax.

Comment: This. `help` is pretty much what I needed.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, yup, that's exactly what `help [` says!

Comment: Note that the `bash(1)` man page is absurdly long on most systems.  IMHO `man(1)` is a poor interface for reading it.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the man page for the shell you're using.  For `bash`, the flow control statements are documented under 'SHELL GRAMMAR' -> 'Compound Commands'.

Answer (score 1):

These are builtins of the shell you are using. So, `man bash` or equivalent for your shell. Particularly for `bash`, the man page is not too long and a very good read. Go through it and you will have a much better feeling what's possible and how stuff works (at least you know it exists for future reference).

Comment: _builtins_ usually refers to commands that are built into the shell as opposed to executed from files in the filesystem, not to keywords in the shell syntax like `if/then/else`.