# Inconsistency of stderr redirection between tcsh and other shells

Tags: io-redirection, tcsh, stderr

I'm running into issues with redirection in tcsh.

Consider the following commands: `vi --version` and `vi --xxx`.  And let's assume this is on a machine where `vi` supports the `--version` option.  The option `--xxx` is invalid, and therefore `vim` should display something via `stderr`.

By that reasoning, using `2> /dev/null` with both of these commands should give output for the valid case and no output for the invalid case.

And that *is* what I see in bash, zsh, ksh, and dash.

```
$ vi --xxx 2> /dev/null
$ vi --version 2> /dev/null
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 20 2014 16:09:17)
...
```

However, when I try this in tcsh, it gives me *no output* in *both* cases.

```
$ vi --xxx 2> /dev/null
$ vi --version 2> /dev/null
(there is no output here)
```

What is going on here?  Am I redirecting `stderr` incorrectly?

Here is the output of `tcsh --version`:

```
tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (i686-intel-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,nd,color,filec
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This inconsistency is in fact the first reason in the list of reasons  why [csh programming is considered harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

> Or what if you just want to throw away stderr and leave stdout
>   alone?    Pretty simple operation, eh?
>
> ```
> cmd 2>/dev/null
> ```
>
> Works in the Bourne shell.  In the csh, you can only make a pitiful 
>   attempt like this:
>
> ```
> (cmd > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
> ```
>
> But who said that stdout was my tty?  So it's wrong.  This simple
>   operation *CANNOT BE DONE* in the csh.

Comment: *(expletive)*!  I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Or `sh -c 'cmd 2> /dev/null'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's cheating! :-)

Comment: *the first reason in the last of reasons* Is this a biblical reference, or a typo for “list”?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek definitely a typo! Thanks for pointing it out. In fact, I don't even get the biblical reference. Probably because I'm not Christian, I guess.

Comment: OK :) Me neither actually, but I meant http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Matthew-20-16/ .

Answer (score 4):

`2>` is not an operator in `tcsh`, you're using the `>` operator and passing `2` as an argument to `vi`. This *appears* to be okay since both `--xxx` and `--version` exit `vi`.

From `tcsh(1)`:

```
   > name
   >! name
   >& name
   >&! name
           The file name is used as standard output.  If the file does not
           exist then it is created; if the file exists, it is  truncated,
           its previous contents being lost.

           If  the shell variable noclobber is set, then the file must not
           exist or be a character  special  file  (e.g.,  a  terminal  or
           `/dev/null')  or an error results.  This helps prevent acciden‐
           tal destruction of files.  In this case the `!'  forms  can  be
           used to suppress this check.

           The  forms  involving  `&' route the diagnostic output into the
           specified file  as  well  as  the  standard  output.   name  is
           expanded in the same way as `<' input filenames are.
```

So you can use `>&` to redirect *both* stdout and stderr (*"diagnostic output"*). There is no "obvious" way to *only* redirect stderr, and this is a long-standing shortcoming of the C shell, a well-known workaround is:

```
(vi --xxx > /dev/tty) >& /dev/null
```

This works by redirecting stdout to `/dev/tty` (which is the current tty) in a subshell (the parens do the same as in bourne shells), and the output of the subshell (which is only stderr since we redirected stdout) is redirected to `/dev/null` (but this can be anything, like a file).

I don't know what your goal is, but in cases where you can't be sure what shell the user is using, I've found that it's usually best to explicitly set it; there are more shells than "bourne and csh", such as fish, and there may also be slight incompatibilities between different Bourne shells and/or some constructs may "happen" to work in one shell, and don't in another...

Comment: Note that `sh -c 'cmd 2> /dev/null'` happens to work in all the shells of the Bourne, csh, rc and fish families (on systems where `sh` is a Bourne-like shell).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, that usually works for (very) simple commands, but it quickly becomes complex due to quoting issues, and people often make mistakes here.

Comment: Yes, writing [shell-agnostic code can be a bit tricky](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/22565). (ツ)