# Subshell and process substitution

Tags: process-substitution, subshell

Apologies if this is a basic question - I'm stuck trying to solve a larger problem, and it's come down to how a shell script is invoked - directly (`shellScript.sh`) or using `sh shellScript.sh`.

Here's a model for the problem:

When I execute on bash:

```
cat <(echo 'Hello')
```

I see the output

```
Hello
```

But when I use:

```
sh -c "cat <(echo 'Hello')"
```

I see errors:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(echo 'Hello')'
```

I've tried escaping the `<`, `(` and `)` in various combinations, but I don't see the output anywhere. What am I missing here?

My actual problem is that I'm passing a `<()` as an input argument to a python script within a shell script, and while it works fine when I invoke the shell script using just the name, if I use `sh` to invoke it, I get errors similar to what I've shown above.

Thank you!

Comment: try `bash -c "cat <(echo 'Hello')"`.  If you're using Debian/Ubuntu, you most likely have `dash`  as your `/bin/sh`.  see: https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/

Comment: It doesn't even matter if `sh` is linked to `bash`, when invoked as `sh` it operates in "POSIX mode" and wouldn't support that feature

Comment: @steeldriver, `bash` disables `<(...)` when invoked as `sh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Process substitution is a feature that originated in the Korn shell in the 80s (first documented in ksh86). At the time, it was only available on systems that had support for `/dev/fd/<n>` files.

Later, the feature was added to `zsh` (from the start: 1990) and `bash` (in 1993). `zsh` was using temporary named pipes to implement it, while `bash` was using `/dev/fd/<n>` where available and named pipes otherwise. `zsh` switched to using `/dev/fd/<n>` where available in `2.6-beta17` in 1996.

Support for process substitution via named pipes on systems without `/dev/fd` was only added to `ksh` in `ksh93u+` in 2012. The public domain clone of `ksh` doesn't support it.

To my knowledge, no other Bourne-like shell supports it (`rc`, `es`, `fish`, non-Bourne-like shells support it but with a different syntax). `yash` has a `<(...)` construct, but that's for *process redirection*.

While quite useful, the feature was never standardized by POSIX. So, one can't expect to find it in `sh`, so shouldn't use it in a `sh` script.

Though the behaviour for `<(...)` is unspecified in POSIX, (so there would be no harm in retaining it), `bash` disables the feature when called as `sh` or when called with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` in its environment.

So, if you have a script that uses `<(...)`, you should use a shell that supports the feature to interpret it like `zsh`, `bash` or AT&T `ksh` (of course, you need to make sure the rest of the syntax of script is also compatible with that shell).

In any case:

```
cat <(cmd)
```

Can be written:

```
cmd | cat
```

Or just

```
cmd
```

For a command other than `cat` (that needs to be passed data via a file given as argument), on systems with `/dev/fd/x`, you can always do:

```
something | that-cmd /dev/stdin
```

Or if you need `that-cmd`'s stdin to be preserved:

```
{ something 3<&- | that-cmd /dev/fd/4 4<&0 <&3 3<&-; } 3<&0
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have a few follow up questions/remarks. My cat/echo example is just that - a base example. My actual use case involves a python script that takes in 3 inputs, one of which is being passed at the moment as a `<(...)`. This py script is being used within a shell script, and if I run the shell script using just its name (in which case it uses the bash interpreter), it works fine.

Comment: Now, when I use `sh script.sh`, it uses bash too, because that's the default shell on the HPC that I use. Is there any way I can ensure the script is invoked only using bash and not anything else? As in, can I check within the script if the script was invoked using `bash script.sh` or `sh script.sh`?

Comment: @Ram, see [What is the portable (POSIX) way to achieve process substitution?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/309594) for instance. You'd want to stop giving your script a `sh` extension if it's not a `sh` script, and use a shebang with the correct interpreter like `#! /path/to/bash -`. If you want to check that the shell is `bash` in your script, try `[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]`, and whether it's in POSIX mode with `[ -o posix ]`.

Comment: I found another of your answers very useful to my situation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/135331 I'm going to see if I can incorporate that into my script.

Comment: Tried editing my previous comment, that didn't work. Anyway, 
it looks like `which_interpreter` won't work in my case. I'm going to have to package my scripts into Modulefiles and hope that the user doesn't bypass the proper usage, I guess. I could also error out on a POSIX shell, or change my script to be POSIX compliant. Hmmm. Thank you for your time, @stéphane-chazelas