# sh is evaluating bash code from parent shell, and breaking down

Tags: shell-script, debugging

I have this code in a **bash** script:

```
r2g(){

   echo "executable is: $0"  # "/bin/bash"

  (
      set -e;
      r2g_internal "$@" \
       2> >( while read line; do echo "r2g error: $line"; done ) \
       1> >( while read line; do echo "r2g: $line"; done )
  )

    exit_code="$?"
    if [[ "$exit_code" != "0" ]]; then
        echo "something experienced an error, to see log, run: r2g_view_log";
        return 1;
    fi
}
```

what's happening is that after `r2g_internal` runs, sh is launched by some process and it apparently tries to resource the bash env, and I get his weird syntax error from sh:

```
r2g error: sh: r2g: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
r2g error: sh: r2g: line 2: ` r2g_internal "$@" 2> >( while read line; do echo "r2g error: $line"; done ) > >( while read line; do echo "r2g: $line"; done ) );'
r2g error: sh: error importing function definition for `r2g'
```

I made a video demoing the problem:
https://www.useloom.com/share/82f23ebfe6754412a20be057957e45f4

and a follow up vid:
https://www.useloom.com/share/0465c2857cc244879b52b7bdb516243e

when `npm install` runs, some `sh` process must be launched by `npm`..`git` also seems to launch an `sh` process sometimes when I run git commands, and the same type of syntax errors show up in the terminal in that case.

**I cannot  figure out why a sh process launched via bash would then try to source some of the bash code from the parent shell/env?**

The video makes the problem clearer (I hope).

if I call `unset -f r2g`, the problem goes away immediately. So I guess `/bin/sh` is calling my r2g function, but I don't know how or why.

Here is the source for r2g and r2g_internal together:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/0fa7e3d6b75a65b17b6b126a7bec3397

Comment: It looks to me as though `sh` is reading the script file that you intend for bash.

Comment: nah in the video I demonstrate that to not be the case (as far as I can tell)

Comment: `sh` is definitely evaluating the script, but why `sh` is evaluating the script is not clear

Comment: You should post what `r2g_internal` code

Comment: Sure thing, here is the code: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/0fa7e3d6b75a65b17b6b126a7bec3397

Comment: What is the shell that's running in the WebStorm terminal?

Comment: it's running `/bin/bash`, I show that in the video

Comment: You're using `>(...)` and `[[`. These are [bashisms](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)   (Well, technically, process substitution [originated in ksh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364012/85039)  ), but the point is that `/bin/sh` doesn't  have these, and if you use `/bin/sh`, make sure your script uses only the stuff that it understands. If there is no portability requirement or POSIX compiance, then just use `/bin/bash` and call it a day.

Comment: I am not the one calling `sh` someone else is...the mystery is not that `sh` is being called by some subprocess, the mystery is why `sh` is invoking `r2g`

Comment: What's the `postinstall.sh` doing in your video and does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: postinstall.sh shouldnt have anything to do with it, its just copying files but not executing any of them

Answer (score 3):

This won't probably solve your problem, just take a moment for a few notes, too long for a comment:

- If you don't need to do so, don't *structure* your code as a single line, I am quoting:

  > ```
  > r2g_internal "$@"  2> >( while read line; do echo "r2g error: $line"; done ) 1> >( while read line; do echo "r2g: $line"; done )
  > ```

  It is unreadable for others and even to you I suspect.
- I'll start from the beginning:

  I don't see a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) like:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  or

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ```

  and so on.
- If you don't need Bash, but this shell script seems to need it, use [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) `sh` for portability purposes.
- Since `exit_code` is used only once, you can avoid it.
- You don't need to quote what number always is. In this instance `"$?"`.
- Avoid Bash-specific `[[ .. ]]`, and use classic test command instead. In this instance:

  ```
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  ```
- You don't need a semi-colon at the end of the line, you may use structure like this one:

  ```
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
      echo "something experienced an error, to see log, run: r2g_view_log"
      return 1
  fi
  ```
- Use `-r` switch with `read`. Read more about this topic [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162).
- I made a few other adjustments, check it out, please.
- I'm unsure, if that is intentional, but I will suppose not; where you used `return 1`, from what I can see, should be `exit 1`.
- The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) can contain the `set -e` as follows:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash -e
  ```

---

Rewritten based on above:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

r2g()
{

    echo "executable name is: $0"

    r2g_internal "$@" 2> >( while read -r line; do echo "r2g error: $line"; done ) >( while read -r line; do echo "r2g: $line"; done )

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "something experienced an error, to see log, run: r2g_view_log"
        exit 1
    fi

}
```

Comment: if i use set -e globally and it gets set in my shell, any command that exits with non zero will close the terminal window. this script is getting sourced by all bash shells so..

Comment: the shebang/hashbang also doesnt matter. that wont determine which process calls the function.

Answer (score -1):

No offence but have you tried to read and understand error message:

> syntax error near unexpected token `**>**'

It explicitly tells that your code contains obvious error: `2> >(`.
'**>**' is to direct standard output into file. Your are trying to direct output of r2g_internal to script reading from standard input. You must use '**|**' not '>'.

And one more error -- you can direct stdout and stderr to separate files but you can not easily direct them to separate scripts. You will have to write them first into files and then process them separately.

```
r2g_internal "$@" 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
cat stderr.txt | ( while read line; do echo "r2g error: $line"; done )
cat stdout.txt | ( while read line; do echo "r2g: $line"; done )
```

Comment: Note that using process substitution (`>(...)`) is _exactly_ what he wants to be doing to filter the output from `r2g_internal` as it arrives.

Comment: Although process substitution is available only in ksh bash zsh -- and bash not when POSIX mode, which may be the cause of the error message. Cf https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309547/what-is-the-portable-posix-way-to-achieve-process-substitution

Comment: well it says it's `sh` that is barfing on the syntax