# Add command output as variable; cross-platform syntax

Tags: windows, variable

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can use command output as variable, use cross-platform syntax.

---

### 2. Example

For example, I want [**get URL of my remote git repository**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880000/5951529):

```bash
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-EEOT0TN /cygdrive/d/SashaBranchReleaseIt
$ git ls-remote --get-url
https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaBranchReleaseIt.git
```

I [**run command**](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Command_substitution) in Linux/Cygwin:

```bash
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-EEOT0TN /cygdrive/d/SashaBranchReleaseIt
$ echo "URL is `git ls-remote --get-url`"
URL is https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaBranchReleaseIt.git
```

I run the same command in Windows `cmd.exe`.

```shell
D:\SashaBranchReleaseIt>echo "URL is `git ls-remote --get-url`"
URL is `git ls-remote --get-url`
```

or

```shell
D:\SashaBranchReleaseIt>echo "URL is $(git ls-remote --get-url)"
URL is $(git ls-remote --get-url)
```

doesn't work.

I don't find syntax, that will be compatible with Windows and UNIX both.

---

### 3. Conditions

#### 3.1. Not expected

I'm looking for a solution, that would be possible run command in default Windows `cmd.exe`. Windows user is not obliged to establish Cygwin, Bash for Windows or another terminal.

#### 3.2. Expected

Windows user [**can add in `Path` environment variable**](https://lifehacker.com/362316/use-unix-commands-in-windows-built-in-command-prompt) path to Cygwin, [**GnuWin32 CoreUtils**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gnuwin32-coreutils.install) commands or path for any UNIX tools, that ported to Windows.

---

### 4. Not helped

1. I don't find, how I can solve my problem in answers for [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/5951529).

---

### 5. Do not offer

1. Yes, I know, that in Windows I can get similar behavior ([**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340018/5951529)), but them Windows-specific. I'm looking for cross-platform command, not Windows-specific.

Comment: Seems abitious; good luck! Perhaps [this attempt](https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/which_interpreter) will ... help?

Comment: Related only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71121/117549

Comment: Syntax of Unix shell scripts and Windows batch files is completely different, except for a couple of things that Windows copied (e.g. I/O redirection and piping). I don't think what you want is possible.