# How to understand which shell a particular code belongs to without knowledge about the shell?

Tags: bash, tcsh

I get to understand that this code is for `bash` shell

```
for f in $file.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
do
  mv $f $f.pdb
done
```

And this code is for `tcsh` shell

```
foreach f ( file.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )
  mv $f $f.pdb
end
```

This I understood after reading from references. As a learner, I had the perception that both the codes will work in `bash`. Is there a way to find out which shell a particular code will work without full knowledge about the different shell. Extending is there a way to make code work on all the shell independent of the type of shell of Linux it was written on?

Comment: Can't resist mentioning https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137/117549

Comment: Ordinarily, one knows what language one writes code in. You may treat each shell as a separate language. If you write `bash` code, don't expect to be able to run it with `sh` or `tcsh` or `zsh`.  It may work, just like running some Python statements with a Perl interpreter may possibly work, but it would be based on luck, mostly.  Usually, the correct interpreter is indicated by the `#!` line at the top of the script.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I really wish you had not mentioned that page. It gives me a headache just looking at it. :)

Comment: When writing the code specify the interpreter at the top (in the first line): e.g. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I sympathize to an extent, but the mainstream English usage is that "code" is an uncountable noun in contexts such as these,

Comment: @JeffSchaller♦, thanks for providing a link to some really interesting material

Comment: See also http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/shell-differences/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for f in $file.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9]
do
mv $f $f.pdb
done
```

Is syntactically valid code in `csh`, `tcsh` and all shells of the Bourne family (ash, bash, zsh, ksh, zsh, mksh, yash...) but it's in `zsh` that it's most likely to be doing something useful.

If the intent of that code is to add a `.pdb` suffix to the names of files in the current directory that start with the contents of the `$file` shell variable and end in `.docked.` followed by 3 ASCII decimal digits, in `bash`, you'd need:

```
shopt -s failglob
for f in "$file".docked.[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]
do
mv -- "$f" "$f.pdb"
done
```

(the `--` is needed regardless of the shell) as in `bash`

- like in the Korn shell, you need to quote parameter expansions as otherwise they undergo split+glob
- `[0-9]` generally matches a lot more characters than just 0123456789, the list of which varies with the locale and the system. You need `[0123456789]` in `bash` to match on 0123456789 only (and no, [the `globasciiranges` option of recent versions doesn't help](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html)).
- globs are left unexpanded when they don't match, so you'd get one pass in the loop with a `$f` containing `contents-of-file-variable.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9]` if there was no matching file. `failglob` (to get a behaviour similar to that of csh or zsh) or `nullglob` (an option copied from `zsh`) address that.

```
foreach f ( file.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )
  mv $f $f.pdb
end
```

Does look like `csh` syntax, but again that's rather `zsh` syntax. In `(t)csh` that should rather be:

```
foreach f ( file.docked.[0-9][0-9][0-9] )
  mv -- $f:q $f:q.pdb
end
```

(though in that particular case, the `:q`s are not strictly necessary as contrary to the other sample, the file names are guaranteed not to contain SPC, TAB, LF or wildcard characters).

Writing code that is valid and does the same thing in completely different languages is very tricky. It's generally called *[polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) coding*. The [Code Golf stackexchange sister site has a section for that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyglot). But that's not the kind of thing you would want to do normally.

See [this example on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71137) as an example of the kind of length you need to go to to achieve it.

Comment: Can you explain the `shopt -s failglob` a bit more deep. I read the documentation in `man bash` and found the following for `failglob` -- `If set, patterns which fail to  match  filenames  during
pathname expansion result in an expansion error.` So by means of setting it, are you making it to show expansion error?

Comment: Also what does the `--` in `mv` stand for ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M With `failglob` you get an error instead of one pass in the loop with a bogus filename when the glob fails to match any file. About `--`, see [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376)

Comment: This fixes it. Done.