# I can't find .bashrc on distro astro

Tags: bashrc

I'm using `distro astro 3`, I tried to add something to `.bashrc` but I couldn't find it.

When I ran the command `ls -a ~`, I could find only  .`bash_history` & `.bash_logout` should I create a `.bashrc` or is there another shell being used for distro astro?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash` ([you need to establish that you are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal)), then you may create `~/.bashrc` if you wish.  This file will be read by interactive shell when they start up.

Login bash shells will use `~/.bash_login`, but will pick up `~/.profile` if the former does not exist.